Small 6 pound Yorkie was accidentally given Pimobendan
My 6 pound Yorkie accidentally consumed a dose of Pimobendan meant for our nearly 20 pound dog. Called poison control immediately, and I mean literal minutes after. It’s 2.5 mg per pill, and we give our 20 pound dog half pills twice a day. So essentially, my 6 pound Yorkie (with zero heart issues) ate 1.25 mg of Pimobendan. They told us to monitor her for any of the usual symptoms, and I noticed when I listened to her heart, it was quite rapid. It seems to have slowed down some as I’m writing this, but should I be worried? This happened a little after 9 PM and it is now 1:56 AM.
Poison control said this shouldn’t be life threatening (I asked point blank), but I just need the peace of mind. Is it worth it to sit at the emergency vet ‘just incase’? She’s not thrown up or been lethargic; she wanted to play a couple hours later. But after hearing her rapid heart beat I’m glad I didn’t continue to let her run around. Should I worry about any damage to her heart? This is the only time it’s ever happened. Feel free to be blunt and let me know if I’ve no reason to worry as much as I’m am!
Edit: slightly elevated heart rate, but ultimately she was fine. Hope this post helps someone in a similar situation.

Emergency questions generally do not belong on stack exchange. As this example illustrates, it can take many hours for somebody merely to comment on them, never mind give a useful answer. If you think you might need to be at the vet, either go to the vet, or phone the vet and ask if you should be there; either one will get you an answer in real time. If it's after hours, start by checking whether your local animal welfare organization has overnight clinic services. When my cat was in crisis I did check him in for a few days.
